# Raspberry Pi as internet forwarder

Tags: networking, local-area-network, ethernet

I thought about building a device that will behave as a forwarder with VPN. I know that I can e.g. take the internet cable, connect it to rpi, turn on vpn and create wifi hotspot. But I wanted it to be more private device and I can't find any information if it's even possible. So I thought about connecting internet cable to rpi, turning on vpn and then connecting second internet cable to another ethernet port. Then I could connect it to e.g. console and play/watch videos with VPN. For the clarity, it would look like this:
Router => ethernet cable => Raspberry pi with vpn => ethernet cable => console or pc

My question is:
Is it possible to have two ethernet ports in raspberry pi that could behave like this? My problem is that I don't know how to put it in words to find similar articles in google so even that would be very helpful.

Comment: The question is off topic, but check other single board computers aside from the raspberry pi. There are some that already have dual Ethernet ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you'll have to buy a USB <--> ETH adapter in order to have two ethernet adapters. After that, you can simply follow intructions to configure your raspi as a router, VPN server, etc...
If there is no private zone under a ETH adapter, you can simply configure your systme to act as a router, or anything you want (ETH cables are two-way data ;) )

I'm not sure about the need of using a raspi for that, why don't you directly use a VPN client on your devices ?

Comment: Because e.g. on PS5 I can't install any VPN but I want VPN network there. My router does not support any VPN so I wanted to do this project for fun. I can't use any other router because my ISP provides the exact device to connect to internet.

Comment: Then you have to install a VPN client on raspi, next configure your raspi to act as router, and finally force your device to route all the traffic throught the raspi. I'm not sure that performances will be nice :/